# What this regular expression - regexp does?

Tags: regex

Can someone please explain what this regexp matches?

`#\b(https://exampleurl.com/)([^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#`

I have no experience with regexp and I need to know what this one does.

Comment: Check here:- http://regex101.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying with [link](http://regex101.com/r/hX2cJ7/2). It explains all:

> **/[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|))/**
>
> **[^\s()<>]+** match a single character not present in the list below
>
> **Quantifier:** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> **\s** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
>
> **()<>** a single character in the list ()<> literally (case sensitive)
>
> **(?:([\w\d]+)|([^[:punct:]\s]|))** Non-capturing group
>
> **1st Alternative:** ([\w\d]+)
>
> **\(** matches the character ( literally
>
> **[\w\d]+** match a single character present in the list below
>
> **Quantifier:** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> **\w** match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
>
> **\d** match a digit [0-9]
>
> **\)** matches the character ) literally
>
> **2nd Alternative:** ([^[:punct:]\s]|)
>
> 1st Capturing group ([^[:punct:]\s]|)
>
> **1st Alternative:** [^[:punct:]\s]
>
> **[^[:punct:]\s]** match a single character not present in the list below
>
> **[:punct:]** matches punctuation characters [POSIX]
>
> **\s** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
>
> **2nd Alternative:** ([^[:punct:]\s]|)
>
> 1st Capturing group ([^[:punct:]\s]|)
>
> **1st Alternative:** [^[:punct:]\s]
>
> **[^[:punct:]\s]** match a single character not present in the list below
>
> **[:punct:]** matches punctuation characters [POSIX]
>
> **\s** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
>
> **2nd Alternative:** (null, matches any position)

Comment: `[:punct:]` is a POSIX character class. Use the PHP/PCRE flavor to get a correct interpretation of the regex, not JavaScript.

Comment: I fixed the missing backslashes. Still, the lack of indentation makes this very hard to read.